# Android Toggle Button not working properly for Password Field

Tags: android, android-layout

When I Click on the Toggle Button, it changes the Password field to Normal looking Text, But when I click on it Again, It doesnt change the Text field to Password Type back. Why is that so ?

Here is my code,

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.text);
chkcmd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but3);
passtog = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.tb1);
input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);
display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv2);
passtog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View V) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

if(passtog.isChecked())
{
input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
}

else if(!passtog.isChecked())
{
input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
}
}
});
```

Comment: use Input.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | Input.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD  instead of using Input.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT only

Answer (score 1):

Since the Support Library v24.2.0. you can achivie this very easy

What you need to do is just:

1. Add the design library to your dependecies

   ```
   dependencies {
        compile "com.android.support:design:25.1.0"
   }
   ```
2. Use `TextInputEditText` in conjunction with `TextInputLayout`

   ```
   <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
       android:id="@+id/etPasswordLayout"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

       <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
           android:id="@+id/etPassword"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:hint="@string/password_hint"
           android:inputType="textPassword"/>
   </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
   ```

`passwordToggleEnabled` attribute will make the password toggle appear

3. In your root layout don't forget to add `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`
4. You can customize your password toggle by using:

`app:passwordToggleDrawable` - Drawable to use as the password input visibility toggle icon.
`app:passwordToggleTint` - Icon to use for the password input visibility toggle.
`app:passwordToggleTintMode` - Blending mode used to apply the background tint.

More details in [TextInputLayout documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Besides implementing the ClickListener you should use the CheckChangedListener as below:

> ```
> passtog.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
>      @Override
>       public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
>         // Save the state here
>       if(isChecked)
>        {
>         input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
>         }
>        else
>         {
>          input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
>          }
>      }
>   });
> ```